# Selenium node chrome debug with multiple VNC ports in docker compose file

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, selenium-grid

The below configuration in docker-compose file with a replica of 5 will create five containers with same VNC port and different internal IP or hostname. If we did the same thing on an ec2 machine then how we access those VNC desktops via public IP?

```
chrome_node:
image: selenium/node-chrome-debug:3.141.59-gold
depends_on:
  - hub
environment:
  - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
  - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
networks:
  - test
entrypoint: bash -c 'SE_OPTS="-host $$HOSTNAME -port 5557" /opt/bin/entry_point.sh'
ports:
  - "5557:5900"
deploy:
  replicas: 5
```

Adding the same entry multiple times in docker-compose file with different IP will do the trick but I am looking for any other alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change ports section to

```
  ports:
    - "5900-5999:5900"
```